# Use Oracle Apex to read csv line by line and validate data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, csv, oracle-apex

Now, I installed Oracle database and Apex into my local server.

I also create a table

```
CREATE TABLE FAC_CODE_CPQLDN(    
    ID NUMBER(10), 
    CODE NVARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, 
    NAME NVARCHAR2(1000), 
    DESCRIPTION BLOB, 
    PARENT_ID NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT FAC_CODE_CPQLDN_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

How can I use Oracle Apex to read csv file line by line, store into "list_value" to validate before inserting into database?

Comment: Have you tried the Data Loading Apex feature? Create Page -> **Data Loading**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv less than 50 columns ( I think it is your case)

```
Excel2Collection [Plug-in]
```

Else

```
Implement your own PL/SQL PROCEDURE PARSE_CSV
```